# Appeal a duplicate question: the rationale was based the perception of similar answers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicate-answers

[Why does Firefox treat Helvetica differently from Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573445/why-does-firefox-treat-helvetica-differently-from-chrome) was marked as a duplicate of [CSS font differences between browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370323/css-font-differences-between-browsers). There was no clear explanation, save for this comment:

“IMO, the answer applies equally well here: ‘But as hard as you try, you won't get the 100% same look. This is because of the different font rendering strategies browsers and OS use.’”

I updated my question with an appeal (see “UPDATE 2”) but the users who marked it as a duplicate aren’t as quick to respond as they were to close the question.

Can someone at least explain what community rules apply here to clarify the situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, agreed:

The answers to that question don't help you (you want "why", not "how to fix".)
Even if the current answers did fit, if you're asking a different question, it shouldn't be treated as a dupe, as some other answers might fit one and not the other and be better.

Re-opened.